# Facebook Leadgen webhook does not include ad_id nor adgroup_id

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-webhooks

### **Issue:**

I have configured webhooks in my Facebook App to send `leadgen` data to my web application. It works fine for the most part and I receive the webhooks in real time but the the fields `adgroup_id` and `ad_id` are not present in the response object as it should be according to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/retrieving#webhook-response).

This is one example of the leadgen webhooks I receive:

```
{
    "entry": [
        {
            "id": "105329XXXXXXXXX",
            "time": 1679056584,
            "changes": [
                {
                    "value": {
                        "created_time": 1679056582,
                        "leadgen_id": "89738XXXXXXXXX",
                        "page_id": "105329XXXXXXXXX",
                        "form_id": "580189XXXXXXXXX"
                    },
                    "field": "leadgen"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "object": "page"
}
```

I need these fields to be able to fetch the Facebook campaign that these leads belong to.

When I access the leadgen data making the following request: [https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/{leadgen_id}](https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/%7Bleadgen_id%7D) It does not included the `ad_id` or `campaign_id` either.

If I add field params in the request: [https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/{leadgen_id}?fields=ad_id,campaign_id](https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/%7Bleadgen_id%7D?fields=ad_id,campaign_id). I only receive the `leadgen_id`. It is worth mentioning that when I make this request on the [Graph Api Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and hover over the selected fields (ad_id,campaign_id), it shows the following message:

> Field is empty or disallowed by the access token

The fields can't be empty because there is an `ad_id` and `campaign_id` related to that lead. But I still don't understand what permission I am missing if that is the case.

### **App settings:**

The app is in **Live Mode** and its App type is **None**.

We have been approved as Tech Provider by Facebook and have Business Verification.

##### Facebook Login

Facebook login is implemented through a custom oauth flow that requests the following permissions since these are the ones the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/retrieving#permissions) requires:

- `leads_retrieval`
- `ads_management`
- `pages_show_list`
- `pages_manage_metadata`
- `pages_read_engagement`
- `pages_manage_ads`

All of these permissions have been approved by App Review and have Advanced Access.

##### Webhooks

Only the page `leadgen` webhook is subscribed.

##### Marketing API

The Ads API access level is **development**.

### **Attempts to solve it:**

I suspected it is a permissions issue. So we tested it adding the `ads_read` permission but it still did not work. The app review to get the advanced access to this permission was rejected because Facebook said that the permission is not needed for the feature.

Then I thought it may be because of the Ads API access (development). I tried to request an app review to get advanced access to `Ads Management Standard Access` but I can not do it since I have not made at least 1500 requests to the related endpoints.

What is the cause of the leadgen webhooks missing the `ad_id` and `adgroup_id` fields?. Or the leadgen response missing the `ad_id` and `campaign_id`?

Comment: What happens when you request details for the received `leadgen_id`, do you get the `ad_id` in the return for that then?

Comment: @cbroe When I make a request to "https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/91020XXXXXX" I receive the following lead data: 



`{
    "created_time": "2023-03-21T11:27:35+0000",
    "id": "91020XXXXXX",
    "field_data": [  omited. It only includes the answers to the form. No ad_id, or campaign_id ]
}`



If I add field params to the request: "?fields=ad_id,campaign_id" I only receive the leadgen_id. 

It is interesting that when I use the Graph API Explorer and hover over those fields (ad_id or campaign_id) it shows this message:  "Field is empty or disallowed by the access token"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that leads created using the Lead Ads Testing tool never include the `ad_id` or `adgroup_id`. Neither do the leads created by clicking on an ad shared via shareable link. Only real leads generated by real users clicking on the live ad include this info in the leadgen webhook payload.

This is a bummer since the **Sandbox Ad Account Management** tools are "temporary" disabled and the only way to test this is by publishing a real ad and receiving real leads. This makes the development process much more difficult.

Meta should really address this.